# Tensorflow parse_single_example returns all dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator, tfrecord

I'm creating a basic [LinearClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier) in Tensorflow, but it seems that my input function returns the whole dataset at the first iteration, instead of just one example & its label.

My TFRecord has the following structure (obtained with `print( tf.train.Example.FromString(example.SerializeToString()))` )

```proto
features {
  feature {
    key: "attackType"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 0
        value: 0
        ...
  feature {
    key: "dst_ip_addr"
    value {
       bytes_list {
        value: "OPENSTACK_NET"
        value: "EXT_SERVER"
        ...
```

It seems the TFRecord file is well formatted. However, when I try to parse it with the following snippet:

```python
def input_fn_train(repeat=10, batch_size=32):
    """
    Reads dataset from tfrecord, apply parser with map
    """
    # Import MNIST data
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([processed_bucket+processed_key])

    # Map the parser over dataset, and batch results by up to batch_size
    dataset = dataset.map(_decode)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset

def _decode(serialized_ex):
    features={

        'src_ip_addr': tf.FixedLenFeature(src_ip_size,tf.string),
        'src_pt': tf.FixedLenFeature(src_pt_size,tf.int64),
        'dst_ip_addr': tf.FixedLenFeature(dst_ip_size,tf.string),
        'dst_pt': tf.FixedLenFeature(dst_pt_size,tf.int64),
        'proto': tf.FixedLenFeature(proto_size,tf.string),
        'packets': tf.FixedLenFeature(packets_size,tf.int64),
        'subnet': tf.FixedLenFeature(subnet_size,tf.int64),
        'attackType': tf.FixedLenFeature(attack_type_size,tf.int64)

    }
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_ex, features)
    label = parsed_features.pop('attackType')
    return parsed_features, label


sess = tf.Session()

it = input_fn_train().make_one_shot_iterator()
print(sess.run(it.get_next()))
```

It shows that `it.get_next()` returns

> ({'dst_ip_addr': array([[b'OPENSTACK_NET', b'EXT_SERVER',...

**This is incorrect since it yields an array of array**! The result should be

> array([b'OPENSTACK_NET',...

Any thoughts ? I've been trying to change the shape parameter of FixedLenFeature, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems it's the `dataset.batch` command that created this strange behavior. Removed it, and it works fine now !